# Getting error after updating android studio from 3.2 to 3.3

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated Android Studio from 3.2 to 3.3

I am getting this error:

> "ERROR: Could not initialize class
>   com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin"

Comment: use this dependency `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'` on your build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

go to File> Build, Execution, Deployment> Gradle> Android Studio in android studio there tick enable embedded maven repository after clicking Apply and then grudle rebuild and this error will disappear